# Bad performance of maven jar plugin on ubuntu

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, jar

My maven builds are stalling on maven-jar-plugin. It takes in the order of 10-15 seconds to build a normally sized jar file. Creating jar files directly with the jar tool or using the java.util.jar classes is not a problem.

The build stalls between detecting that isUp2Date is false and listing of the jar entries.

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = /home/.../repos/.../zz-test-zip/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) defaultManifestFile = /home/.../repos/.../zz-test-zip/target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[DEBUG]   (f) finalName = zz-test-zip-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) forceCreation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /home/.../repos/.../zz-test-zip/target
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: ...
[DEBUG]   (f) useDefaultManifestFile = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] isUp2date: false (Destination /home/.../repos/.../zz-test-zip/target/zz-test-zip-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar not found.)
** Here the build stalls **
[INFO] Building jar: /home/.../repos/../zz-test-zip/target/zz-test-zip-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

What could cause maven-jar-plugin to take a pause there? I'm on ubuntu 12.04 and Oracle JDK 1.7.0_45. Maven version is 3.0.5 "manual" install, not the one from ubuntu repo. I can also add that the behavior is the same when i run in offline mode, using the `-o` switch.

**UPDATE**

I run mvnDebug and attached the process to eclipse, and when I suspend the main thread when it is "pausing", it invariably shows this call stack:

```
UnixNativeDispatcher.getgrgid(int) line: not available [native method]  
UnixUserPrincipals.fromGid(int) line: 129   
UnixFileAttributes.group() line: 187    
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
Java7Reflector.invoke(Method, Object, Object...) line: 151  
Java7Reflector.getOwnerGroupName(Object) line: 133  
Java7FileAttributes.<init>(File) line: 68   
PlexusIoResourceAttributeUtils.getFileAttributesByPathJava7(File, boolean) line: 330    
PlexusIoResourceAttributeUtils.getFileAttributesByPath(File, Logger, int, boolean, boolean) line: 224   
PlexusIoResourceAttributeUtils.getFileAttributesByPath(File) line: 195  
PlexusIoFileResourceCollection.getResources() line: 177 
AbstractArchiver$1.hasNext() line: 433  
JarArchiver(AbstractZipArchiver).createArchiveMain() line: 233  
JarArchiver(AbstractZipArchiver).execute() line: 211
```

Comment: Can you show the pom file of that build ?

Comment: maven version? This is maven from apache.org or from ubuntu repo?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm afraid not, but there's nothing special in the pom files.

Comment: @MariuszS See update: not the ubuntu stuff.

Comment: I have the same exact problem.  Are you running in a NIS setup where the user/group information is doing a YP lookup?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same behavior.  Is this some bizarreness in JarArchiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I upgrade the maven-jar-plugin to 2.6, the problem is gone.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <index>true</index>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Wish it helps for your case.